# google play services ads - ads still refreshing after activity destroyed

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

Pretty straightforward problem:

When app is destroyed, I still see messages pertaining to ads in the logcat:

```
ads   Scheduling ad refresh 60000 ms from now.
ads   ad is not visible, not refreshing ad.
```

Is this normal? And if not, how do you prevent this from happening?

/e I have tried making the `adRequest = null` and `adview.destroy() in onDestroy();

/e2 Versions:

Google Play Services lib revision 15

SDK tools 22.6.1

SDK platform tools 19.0.1

Android Developer Tools 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759

Solution (from Google Groups User):
Adding adView = null after adView.destroy() has fixed this issue for me

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the Activity has been destroyed? Did #onDestroy get called or is the Activity just hidden in the background?

You might need to call adView#destroy() in Activity#onStop as #onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called even if the Activity is destroyed.

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly certain: I added a Log.e(....) line in onDestroy(), which printed when I closed the activity.

Comment: What version of Admob SDK or Google Play Services are you using?